# coc.nvim: 'self', numbers([0-9]) and strings don't show in CocAction(doHover) show_documentation(?)

Tags: vim, rust, coc.nvim, rust-analyzer

coc.nvim: The word 'self', numbers([0-9]) as well as strings  don't show in CocAction(doHover); the attached image as an example. This is the case in parameters and arguments in documentation provided by `coc.nvim` for rust analyzer.

When I highlight and copy the text, they appear. I think it's a problem of them having the same color as the background.

Help please[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using base16 vim -> https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim and applying the settings in the readme